# How to pass and receive value on url , don't using router in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 pages and 2 controllers: A and B separately. I do not use the Router. I want to pass the value from A by url and get the value on page B

Example: Value in page A: **abc**

Url load page B: https://details.com/pageB/`abc`

I haven't found the documentation yet tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angularjs - how to retrieve data from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546478/angularjs-how-to-retrieve-data-from-url)

Comment: @Alok . tks u . but I've seen . But they use the router. And I don't use a router

Comment: Go for the other answer, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34546598/5362583