# Retrieve GET requests with Javascript in Firefox console

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, automated-tests, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a way to retrieve details of GET requests of a web page using JavaScript? I don't mean parameters of the current page's URL but out-going GET requests.

Example:
If you open google's start page with firefox and toggle developer-tools, in the network tab you can see a number of GET request such as that for the logo which is something like https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

I want to retrieve this URL on console tab using JavaScript. Is it possible to retrieve it via an object attached to the DOM (`document`) or BOM (`window`)?

The reason for my question is: I am in an test automation environment where developer-tools are not available. Only JavaScript is available and I need to check the URL of a GET request issued by the current page. I just mentioned developer-tools because it is the simplest way to reproduce the problem (and the easiest way to verify, if a solution works). But it is more about Firefox/HTTP than test automation as such.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: @parameciostudio No, I had a look at that already. But this is not the point here: As I said I do not want to retrieve the parameters of the page that is shown in Firefox but the requests **issued by that page** and which are listed in the network analysis tab.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible within devtools, but you may be able to use normal JS to make a [global event handler](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) (if it's jQuery) or if using normal JS, replace the XmlHttpRequest object with a duckpunched object that logs the result, as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/1khgqo/how_do_you_diagnose_what_javascript_is_making_an/).

Comment: I like the second approach but I am unable to verify because I can't change the server. If I try in my browser, edit the page, insert the additional script and resend the request there is some warning about blocked "Cross-Origin" request.

Comment: Can you post the script and exact error message you're getting? Are you sure you're not having problems due to CORS in the first place?

Comment: Well, yes it is due to CORS. My manually sent request is blocked due to: "Missing CORS header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing". The requested server is not under my control, so I'm stuck. Anyway, if time permits, I will try to set up a different minimalistic environment to thoroughly test this approach.