# Javascript how to get URL values for my particular URL

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me get the values.

I know there are few question asked about it but I could not frame my logic for given values.

I have a URL as below

> http://crm//WebResources/abaxis_popup?Data=recordid%3dElectrolyte%26sometext%3daw_device%26somemoretext%3dpolyclinic

I have variables and data as follows

---

```
var addParams =encodeURIComponent( "recordid=" + entityLabel + "&sometext=" + entityName + "&somemoretext=" +entityId);
Xrm.Utility.openWebResource('abaxis_popup',addParams ,280,200);
```

---

```
recordId=Electrolyte

sometext =aw_device

somemoretext=polyclinic
```

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to get the values? Can you clarify that, and format the code bits of your question as code?

Comment: I am trying to get values in a HTML file as local variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Comment: I could not get it.I am sorry can you please help me frame it,its my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Pogrindis yes it is equals

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: Just to let you know, you're URL formatting is also incorrect.

Your URL is `http://crm//WebResources/abaxis_popup?Data=recordid%3dElectrolyte`

Which translates to `http://crm//WebResources/abaxis_popup?Data=recordid=Electrolyte`

The double `=`'s after recordid is breaking your GET parameters.

So the `Data` param is being set to `recordid` before anything else happens. Not sure what you want to do here.

In order to remove this from the URL string you could use the following :

```
urlString = urlString.replace(/Data=/g, '');
```

---

As suggested you are posting a duplicate question with a slight difference in HTML URL format.

You have HTML chars instead of regular strings.

So convert them back. 
Our string URL

```
var urlString = "http://crm//WebResources/abaxis_popup?Data=recordid%3dElectrolyte%26sometext%3daw_device%26somemoretext%3dpolyclinic";
```

Replace the HTML chars to the regular text chars.

```
urlString = urlString.replace(/%26/g, '?');
urlString = urlString.replace(/%3d/g, '=');
```

Use the function in the duplicate question answer to parse the params and values 
Generously contributed by : [weltraumpirat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547122/weltraumpirat)

```
function transformToAssocArray( prmstr ) {
    var params = {};
    var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
    for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
        var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
        params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
    }
    return params;
}
```

Use it.

```
var result = transformToAssocArray(urlString);
```

A working example of the proceedure : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nntyjbx/)

Comment: Thank you for ur reply.Yes it is duplicate question and since 4-5 hrs I was trying to work on available ans here but as I said it is mere my Lack ok knowledge and understanding,hence I asked particular to my url.
Also I am trying to call html script in crm with some local values from crm in url and retrieve those values and use in HTML so that I can save them as PDF.
-------------------------------
I tried entire code but when I use alert(result); it gives "object" as o/p 
I also tried alert(result.sometext);
AS sometext in url has electrolyte value but i m getting "undefined" as o/p.
Thanks

Comment: AS you said my url is also wrong how can I improve it so that I get correct result


       var addParams =encodeURIComponent( "recordid=" + entityLabel + "&sometext=" + entityName + "&somemoretext=" +entityId);
Xrm.Utility.openWebResource('abaxis_popup',addParams ,280,200);

Comment: 1 question who should i use result to get value. I am getting correct url now without  data=recordid=
but when I refer other variable lie sometext it still gives me undefinied

Comment: @AnkushChikhale I have updated the answer to include parsing the DATA= out