# How to send a parameter in html link and how to retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, html, href

Here is my html  tag with href

```
<a href='components/home/singleActivity.html?view="search"'>
....
</a>
```

I want to send a string parameter, is it the correct way ?

how to retrieve that parameter in javascript ? and how to send 2 parameters for the same href ?

Answer (score 3):

It should be without quotes `components/home/singleActivity.html?view=search` to send two parameters join them with `&`

```
components/home/singleActivity.html?foo=bar&baz=quux
```

to read them in javascript use this code:

```
var params = {};
location.search.slice(1).split("&").forEach(function(pair) {
   pair = pair.split("=");
   params[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
});
```

Comment: On new browser you can also use the URL object wich makes thinks 10x easier.

Comment: @BrunoSouza I don't think you can get all keys using URL object you can only get value bar and quux if you know foo and baz. See [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/387194)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```html
<a href='components/home/singleActivity.html?view=Search&test2=New'>
MyLink
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to send the parameters in the URL you **donot** need to enclose the value inside quote`('')` or doublequotes`("")`. You just need to send the values (or the multiple values) as shown below..

```
components/home/singleActivity.html?view=search&secondvalue=anythingthatyouthinkof
```

Also keep in mind that you need to keep track of the urlencoding.

And for retrieving the parameters **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)** explains it in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple values you can use `?view=search&key2=value2&key3=value3` and so on.

Moreover to access these parameters you can access the URL using window.location.

Something like

```
var params = window.location.split('?')[1];
```

This will give you everything after the ? in the URL.

Comment: split is method of string not a function.

Comment: My bad. Edited ;-) Thanks