# How do I after button click which opens a webpage, pop an alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, button, submit, alert, contacts

I have a contact form which when the button to submit is clicked redirects to my homepage, when my homepage loads I want a javascript alert to come up saying 'Thanks for contacting us'

Thank you.

Comment: put a query parameter in the url, open that new url. on the page itself check for the query parameter and do the alert if it's there.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Would you like someone to write the javascript for your case? Or have you tried and run into a problem? To help, we would need to see an example of what you have tried, with a specific question about what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a parameter to your URL (www.example.com/?formSubmit=true).

With JS, look for the formSubmit=true. If you see it, create an alert.

To set up the javascript portion, check out this previous question:

[How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)