# How to switch tabs programmatically HTML/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a HTML page which has horizontal tabs defined as follows

```
<ul class="tabs clear has-borderbottom">
    <li class="js-tab selected" data-tab="tab1"><a href="#">TAB 1</a></li>
    <li class="js-tab" data-tab="tab2"><a href="#">TAB 2</a></li>
    <li class="js-tab" data-tab="tab3"><a href="#">TAB 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

When I load the page it opens with TAB 1 opened which is ok for me in all cases. But there is one condition where I want to load TAB 2 as the opening tab instead of tab 1. How can I do this programatically in js?

I use `window.location.href = "/details` to redirect to the above HTML page where I want to display TAB 2 opened be default.

Comment: Are you using any plugin? Do share that info

Comment: plugin for? rendering htmls?

Comment: Share your JavaScript code too.

Comment: use bootstrap visit [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give a parameter with your window.location.href = "/details?tab=2".
Then you can read your GET-Parameter out of the Location with the function posted in:
[How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

```js
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
    .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
        tmp = item.split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Then you have to change your selected-Class onload of the document.
Add a new document.onload-Function, like this:

```js
function doThisOnOnload()
{
  var selected = findGetParameter("tab");
  
  $('.js-tab').removeClass("selected");
  $('[data-tab="tab'+selected+'"]').addClass("selected");
}
```

Therefor jquery has to be injected.

Comment: tab2 does get selected (highlighted) but it does not switch the tab. I can still see tab1 with tab2 underlined(highlighted).

Comment: Then we need to know your javascript, how does it work now?