# jquery: value on $.post that depends on link selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in my application with two hyperlinks. Both of these hyperlinks redirect the user to the same page where they can add information for a new account. When link #1 is selected, one value passed to the controller action must be 1. If the other link is chosen then the value is 2. How can this be done using jquery?

hyperlinks:

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:100px; top:25%; left:50%; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap ">
    <a href="~/rxcard/addaccount" style="color:#444444;">ADD CLINIC</a>     
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; width:100px; top:33%; left:48%; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap">
    <a href="~/rxcard/addaccount" style="color:#444444;">ADD MEDICAL OFFICE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why on Earth do you need to use jQuery for this? Use simple GET parameters.

```
<a href="~/rxcard/addaccount?type=1" style="color:#444444;">ADD MEDICAL OFFICE</a>
```

Note the `?type=1` Passes a get parameter with a value of one.

On the recieving page you can use the folllowing function to check which get parameter was passed.

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
    .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
        tmp = item.split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Use like this: `findGetParameter('type')` to get the value of the `type` from the url.

Got that function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should define a new attribute like data-id your html element after that detect the click action and change the href.

```
<div>
    <a href="~/rxcard/addaccount" data-id='1'>ADD CLINIC</a>     
</div>
<div>
    <a href="~/rxcard/addaccount" data-id='2'>ADD MEDICAL OFFICE</a>
</div>

<script>
$("a").on('click',function(){
    var thiz = $(this);
    thiz.attr('href',thiz.attr('href')+?val=thiz.attr('data-id'));
});
</script>
```

If you have value in initialization you can give different hrefs your anchors. In this scenario you don't need to Jquery or Javascript;

```
<div>
    <a href="~/rxcard/addaccount?val=1">ADD CLINIC</a>     
</div>
<div>
    <a href="~/rxcard/addaccount?val=2">ADD MEDICAL OFFICE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a GET parameter to the links, they will keep pointing to the same URL but also will pass a parameter

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:100px; top:25%; left:50%; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap ">
    <a href="~/rxcard/addaccount?param=1" style="color:#444444;">ADD CLINIC</a>     
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; width:100px; top:33%; left:48%; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap">
    <a href="~/rxcard/addaccount?param=2" style="color:#444444;">ADD MEDICAL OFFICE</a>
</div>
```