# Additional parameters in window.location.replace

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code, I'm trying to determine which button a user presses.

```js
function Navigation(navigating, timed) {
  if (navigating == general) {
    if (timed) {
      window.location.replace('general.html?timed=' + timed);
    } else {
      window.location.replace('general.html');
    }
  } else if (navigating == sport) {
    if (timed) {
      window.location.replace('sport.html?timed=' + timed);
    } else {
      window.location.replace('sport.html');
    }
  } else if (navigating == music) {
    if (timed) {
      window.location.replace('music.html?timed=' + timed);
    } else {
      window.location.replace('music.html');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="general" onclick="Navigation(general, null)">General Knowledge</button>
<button type="button" id="sport" onclick="Navigation(sport, null)">Sport</button>
<button type="button" id="music" onclick="Navigation(music, null)">Music</button>
<button type="button" id="generalTimer" onclick="Navigation(general, 'true')">Timed General Knowledge</button>
<button type="button" id="sportTimer" onclick="Navigation(sport, 'true')">Timed Sport</button>
<button type="button" id="musicTimer" onclick="Navigation(music, 'true')">Timed Music</button>
```

It actually works, however when I get to the next page, I don't know how to get the timed variable to affect the page.

Comment: [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5448545/669576)

Comment: So you are asking how to read the querystring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

## Usage

```
Example URL:
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1&image=awesome.jpg

Calling getQueryVariable("id") - would return "1".
Calling getQueryVariable("image") - would return "awesome.jpg".
```

**Source:** [CSS-TRICKS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url params from `window.location.search`. This function will parse the values, and allow you to get them all or just a single value.

unfortunately it's not working in the debug window due to the ristrictions of the iframe.

```js
function urlParams(key) {
  const search = location.search.slice(1)
    .split(/\=|\&/)
    .filter(val => val !== '')

  const obj = {}
  for (let ii = 0; ii < search.length; ii+=2) {
    obj[search[ii]] = search[ii + 1]
  }
  return key
    ? obj[key]
    : obj
}

console.log(
  urlParams('testing'), // get specific param
  urlParams() // get all params
)
```

Comment: You define the `obj` keyword as `const` and then you define a value to it later. It isn't valid, should be a `var` or `let`.

Comment: @silentw the variable is pointing to the object and that never changes, the properties of the object make no difference.

Comment: You are indeed correct. Sorry, I removed my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use localstorage**
for example:
first save the value that has been choosen to localstorage by code like this
localStorage.nav = navigating; 
and then
for nextpages and whereever you want call the value with
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.nav;
for example write down it with

Comment: @epascarello  sorry, that was just a mistake