# How would I build an AJAX request in rails that uses a param from the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, parameters, coffeescript

If I have a url like `localhost:3000?id=2` what do I need to change to get my AJAX call to use the param?

**page_controller.rb**

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pId = params[:id]
    @p = Plant.where(id: @pId)
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @p.to_json }
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

**page.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $.ajax
    dataType: 'json'
    url: 'index.json'
    success: (data) ->
      alert "Data #{JSON.parse(data)} ---"
```

**development.log** for one page load

```
Processing by PageController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Rendering page/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mPlant Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "plants".* FROM "plants" WHERE "plants"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered page/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 80ms (Views: 69.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/index.json" for ::1 at 2017-01-26 08:07:18 -0800
Processing by PageController#index as JSON
  [1m[36mPlant Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "plants".* FROM "plants" WHERE "plants"."id" IS NULL[0m
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

This is just a very basic example taken from a much more complicated piece of code.  Everything in my original code works except for when I'm trying to access to param.

## update 1

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'index' => 'page#index'
  root "page#index"
end
```

Comment: what do you have in routes?

Comment: @inye updated my post to include the routes

Comment: you read htis article http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI for the Ajax request doesn't include the parameter. You're making a call to `index.json` and not `index.json?id=1`

Comment: I figured it would be something easy like that.  How woluld I grab the param from the URL to use in the json call?  something like 'index.json?id=param[:id]'

Comment: If your goal is to get the parameters from the URL and feed it to your JS, this is a good way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: For those looking for the 'easy' answer I ended up adding the following two lines of code before the ajax call `paramsString = window.location.search.substr(1)`
`searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString)` I then changed the `'index.json'` to `'index.json'+searchParams`