# Is it possible to have URL based authentication with Form based authentication?

Tags: java, tomcat

login page

```html
<form method='post' action='j_security_check'>
 <input type='text' name='j_username'>
 <input type='password' name='j_password'>
</form>
```

content from web.xml

```html
<web-app>
 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>User Auth</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>admin</role-name>
   <role-name>manager</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
   <form-login-page>login.jsp</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>error.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
</web-app>
```

Form based authentication works fine. But if I access the index.jsp directly from http://localhost:8080/index.jsp/j_security_check?j_username=admin&j_password=admin is not working.

Why its not working ?

Comment: `method='post'` but a browser send a GET request (well from what I know), If you really want to do that, you need to manage the GET request too. (but is it really necessary ? Use a redirect page if you really need that)

Comment: As you're using the method='post' in your form, the request is being handled as a post - however, when you're just passing the queryparameters directly as you've indicated - the request will be handled as a get (which is != post) and thus won't work

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting a login from a `POST` request, you can't (correct me if I am wrong) send this directly from the browser URL.

A solution would be to do an other page, a `loginRedirect.jsp` that would send a POST request automaticly.

This would be populate the `<form>` with the parameter passed in the URL and automaticly send an `click` event. Everything in Javascript.

This could be done in the `login` page off course. If there is some parameter in the URL, send the form automaticly.

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript) as source, you can easily read the parameter (and check if there is any) and set the values of the `<input>`. Then generate a click on the `submit` button.