# How to get part of a link and input it into website with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, hyperlink

So I'm trying to make a website where you put in a username and it will give you data about that username using an API. Right now I have it set up so you have to type the username in every time you're on the website, but I was wondering if it's possible to put the username in the link and still be able to retrieve it to put it into an API and use the API's response in the website?

For example, would it be possible to have something like `http://website.com/?username=XXXXXXXXX`and to be able to get the part after `?username=` and to save it to a string or something to put into the API using JavaScript or jQuery? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you saving username in cookie/storage/session after user input?your ways is complex and unreliable.or may be you could use the rest url format like this: `http://{username}.example.com/api` or `http://www.example.com/{user}/api` then your backend always retrieves username from this path and you needn't add parameters manually.

Comment: Mainly because I want it to be possible to send the link to another person, and have it so when they click on it all the information for that user is there without needing for them to put in their username. If you know of a better way to do that I'll take any advice :)

Comment: use the rest url can solve your problem.and then in your server config an urlrewrite to resolve the parameter.like this:
browser: `http://www.example.com/{user}/api`

backend urlrewrite: `http://www.example.com/api?username={user}`

Comment: saving parameters in path nor query having one primary benefit,when user jump to another page,the relative pages url can also retrieves this parameters.