# CodeIgniter AJAX login validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a Bootstrap modal login form. I want to perform AJAX form validation where I want to display the errors using AJAX. All of this is working perfectly but I want the form to redirect to some other view along with some data on successful login.

But here the problem is that I cannot do `$('html').html(data);` as it is although returning the required thing but with different font and without models and few other features.

Everything is working fine when I do the validation without AJAX but in that case, the error does not appear directly, one has to again toggle the model to view the errors.

So overall I just want to use AJAX for displaying the errors but if the error is not there I just want to display the result directly through CodeIgniter as if there was no AJAX Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the HTML but simple change the window location. 
In your success, add this line:

```
$.ajax({
    /*...*/
    success: function(data){
        window.location.href = "index.php/YourNewPage";
    }
    /*...*/
})
```

Make sure your other page is register in your `route.php` as well, so you can acces it via url.

Comment: Tried the same but I want to pass a php value too

Comment: Thats why I am able to load the view from CodeIgniter but not from AJAX

Comment: you could pass the value  in `$_GET` like `window.location.href= "index.php/YourNewPage?id=2"`

Comment: And how can I access that value inside a modal

Comment: in your javascript or in PHP ?

Comment: I am going to access it inside modal in a view

Comment: You can retreive GET parameters in javascript., see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: I am  receiving the value through post

Comment: Can I access the value passed in URL through php(if yes then I will prefer that)

Comment: yea using `$_GET['yourValue']`

Comment: you mean if I passed the value like ...?id=2 then I can access it inside view by $_POST['id']

Comment: Not `$_POST` since you are creating a get request, use `$_GET['id']`

Comment: I am using post method in AJAX

Comment: So can I access the value passed in ....?id=2 format through $_GET even if I have post method in AJAX

Comment: Actually I don't want the user to see the value in url

Comment: you can try to save the value in SEssion and pass it to another page, see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Can't I have something similar to `$('html').html(data);` which will load the entire page and also the javascript. This is misbehaving and not loading the modals and some other features which iss supposed to occur in javascript

Comment: you could but it is a very bad idea, each page should have their own HTML and you should replace one, you should change page.