# Set to true state a checkbox in a different page(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Here's the Script.

**javascript**

```
function linkPageContact(clicked_id){
  if(clicked_id === 'website-design-check'){
        $('#website-design').attr('checked',true);
        window.location.href = "/contact";
    }
  }
}
```

I want to check my checkboxes when I click the button with an `id=website-design-check`.

Here is my HTML.

**first.html**

```
<a href="/contact" target="_blank">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="website-design-check" onclick="linkPageContact(this.id)">Appointment</button>
</a>
```

Here's the second HTML file where checkbox is.

**second.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="website-design" name="website-design">
```

Now how can I achieve what I want base on the description given above. Can anyone help me out guys please. I'm stuck here for an hour. I can't get any reference about getting a checkbox state from another page.

Comment: You need a database or session to hold the data.

Comment: does i really need it???

Comment: Because the event is happening on one page and the changes happening in another page. JavaScript or jquery alone can't do this you need a server to do that.

Comment: do you have any reference or example sir how can i do it on a local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you can modify your button link and add in additional parameters that you can then process on the next page.

The code for the different pages would be like:

**Edit**: I changed it to jQuery, it should work now.

**Script**

```js
function linkPageContact(clicked_id){
  if(clicked_id === 'website-design-check'){
        window.location.href = "second.html?chk=1";
    }
  }
```

**second page**

```html
<input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="website-design" name="website-design">

<script type="text/javascript">
       var url = window.location.href.split("?");
        if(url[1].toLowerCase().includes("chk=1")){
            $('#website-design').attr('checked',true);
        } 
</script>
```

Comment: @PaulKevinMacandili, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: ```<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="website-design-check" onclick="linkPageContact(this.id)">Appointment</button>``` this was my original button to redirect me to my second.html now it doesn't work because i just copy paste your code sir

Comment: @PaulKevinMacandili, take a look at it now, and tell me if it works

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle to other sites via JavaScript or jQuery directly. But there's another way. You can use the GET method to achive this.

First you need to add to the link an attribute like this in your `first.html`:

```
/contact?checkbox=true
```

You can change the link as you want with JavaScript.

Now it will refer to the same page but it can be now different. After that you can receive the parameter with this function on the `second.html`.

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
    tmp = [];
    var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        tmp = items[index].split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I got it from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript) thanks to Bakudan.

**EDIT:**
[image: theory]
So here is an short theory.

When the user clicks the button on the first page, then you change the link from `/contact` to `/contact?checkbox=true`. When the user get forwarded to `second.html` then you change the checkbox depending on the value, which you got from the function `findGetParameter('checkbox')`.

Comment: so i'll just paste this method on my function linkPageContact(){
}|?

Comment: @PaulKevinMacandili No you have to set the function in the second.html to get the GET parameter. Then if it is set to true you can check the box from your second.html via JavaScript.

Comment: can you explain more sir ? i just dont get it im very sorry

Comment: so the whole function is as is . i don't need to change any of them sir?

Comment: @PaulKevinMacandili Exactly

Answer (score 0):

since your checkbox is in another html page, so it's totally normal that you can't get access to it from your first html page!

what I can offer u is using the [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to keep the id and then use it in your second page to check if it's the ID that u want or not.

so change your function to this :

```
function linkPageContact(clicked_id){
    localStorage.setItem("chkId", "clicked_id");
    window.location.href = "/contact";
}
```

then in your second page in page load event do this :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var chkid = localStorage.getItem("chkId");
    if(chkid  === 'website-design-check'){
        $('#website-design').attr('checked',true);
 });
```

Comment: where should i put the jquery sir? on my second.html?

Comment: Yes it should be in your second page which you have your checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

As all have mentioned you need to use session/query string to pass any variable/values to another page.

One click of the first button [first page] add query string parameter - http://example.com?chkboxClicked=true

```
<a href="secondpage.html?chkboxClicked=true>
<button>test button</button>
</a>
```

In the second page- check for the query string value, if present make the checkbox property to true.

In second page-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(window.location.href.contains('chkboxClicked=true')
{
  $('#idOfCheckbox').prop('checked','checked');
}
})
```

Add it and try, it will work.

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: what error you are getting, what is not working, in URL re you able to add the parameter, and check it on the second page.[by adding alert]

Comment: Use the modified code or yours --

function linkPageContact(clicked_id){
  if(clicked_id === 'website-design-check'){
        window.location.href = "/contact?checkboxClicked=true";
    }
  }
}
in second page add this probaly contact.html or aspx..
$(document).ready(function(){
if(window.location.href.contains('checkboxClicked=true')
{
  $('#idOfCheckbox').prop('checked','checked');
}
})
Modified your code itself. check it.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating from one `html` file to another `html` file

You can solve these issue in different approaches

1. using `localStorage`
2. using the query parameters
3. Database or session to hold the data.

In your case if your application is not supporting IE lower versions `localStorage` will be the simple and best solution.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="contact.html" target="_blank">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="website-design-check" onclick="linkPageContact(this.id)">Appointment</button>
    </a> 
    <script>
      function linkPageContact(clicked_id) {
        localStorage.setItem("chkId", clicked_id);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="website-design" name="website-design">
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () { 
        var chkid = localStorage.getItem("chkId");
        if (chkid  === 'website-design-check') {
          $('#website-design').attr('checked', true);
        }  
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```