# How to get parameters coming from URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have html code like this:

```
<form action="getarrayjs.html" method="get">
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"/>
<input type="submit" id="sub1"/>
</form>
```

I need to pass the text1 value to getarrayjs.html page.
That page code is like this:

```
<script>
var x = window.location.search;
document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = x;
</script>

<p id="write"></p>
```

But after submitting, nothing is appear on the getarrayjs.html page. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I'll bet there's an error saying you can't assign to `innerHTML` of `null`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: No any error in the output. Even its not saying Null

Comment: Is your `<script>` really before the `<p>` like you show in the question? Because if it is, `document.getElementById` will fail because the DOM element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yet it was. I corrected, now its working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the window.location object. This code gives you GET without the question mark.

```
window.location.search.substr(1)
```

From your example it will return returnurl=%2Fadmin

EDIT: I took the liberty of changing Qwerty's answer, which is really good, and as he pointed I followed exactly what the OP asked:

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
          tmp = item.split("=");
          if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        });
    return result;
}
```

I removed the duplicated function execution from his code, replacing it a variable ( tmp ) and also I've added decodeURIComponent, exactly as OP asked. I'm not sure if this may or may not be a security issue.

Or otherwise with plain for cycle, which will work even in IE8:

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        tmp = items[index].split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Original answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5448595/8248483

AND THEN:

FIRST CALL `<p id="write"></p>`
and only then

`<script> 
var x = window.location.search; 
document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = x; 
</script>`

Comment: His code just tries to display the entire `window.location.search`. If he gets nothing with that, how will parsing work?

Comment: Use the `findGetParameter` function by entering Your `text1` key.

Comment: His problem had nothing to do with getting the query parameters, it was because he was trying to display it in a DOM element that didn't exist yet.

Comment: Still he will get the `?text1=some_word` but not only `some_word` without code. AND THE MAIN THING IS THAT @Ƥŕaśađ Şŕįɱał MUST FIRST CALL `<p id="write"></p>` and only then `<script>
var x = window.location.search;
document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = x;
</script>`

Comment: Exactly, that's what I said in my comments above.

Comment: This question should just be closed as a duplicate of the question I linked to. I can't do that because I misunderstood it like you did and closed it as a duplicate of a question about parsing the URL parameters.