# print value of URL Parameters hash js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the parameters from a URL using js i have a url :

`http://www.example.com?i=aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=`

i want to decode base64 ?i value and print decode value here using javascript

`<input id="i" type="hidden" value="decode value" />`

Comment: Could you provide some js code? What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var parameterValue = atob(window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)i\=([^&]*)/)[2])
console.log(parameterValue);//"hello world"
document.getElementById('i').value=parameterValue;
```

This might help too :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26995016/957026

Answer (score 0):

you could use the window.location API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

```js
console.log(window.location.search);
```

You will get as a response ?i=some-value

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the value from url and and decode it.

Use below code

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
let x = atob(getUrlVars().i);
console.log(x); // hello world
document.getElementById('i').value = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse URL strings, modern browsers provide a class called `URLSearchParams` and this is the easiest way to extract URL values.

You can create an instance of that class by passing it the `search` property of `window.location` (after removing the initial "?"), and then it will do all the work for you:

```
// eg. https://example.com/?name=Jonathan&age=18&i=aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search.substring(1)); // remove "?"
const name = params.get("name"); // is the string "Jonathan"
const age = parseFloat(params.get("age")); // is the number 18
const i = whateverDecodingFunctionYouUse(params.get("i")); // decoded aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/