# How do I get a URL parameter and add it to a link on the same page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page on my website where users can visit to access the website in the language they need.

For example:

```
<ul class="locale-list">
<li><a title="Deutsch" href="/de-de/" locale="de">Deutsch</a></li>
<li><a title="English" href="/en-en" locale=en">English</a></li>
<li><a title="French" href="/fr-fr/" locale="fr">Français</a></li>
</div>
```

Those links will lead to the homepage in that language.

What I'm trying to do is make it so if someone visits this page from an existing page on the website, they are sent BACK to the previous page via this URL parameter:

```
example.com/languages?target=[page-slug]"
```

The reason for this is because if you a user is viewing the page "Acme" and needs to change the language, the user should click over to the language selector page, click on which which one they want, and it will kick them back to the "Acme" page so they can review the page in that language.

My thought here is that I can snag the 'target' parameter value and have the links update like this:

```
<ul class="locale-list">
<li><a title="Deutsch" href="/de-de/[page-slug]" locale="de">Deutsch</a></li>
<li><a title="English" href="/en-en/[page-slug]" locale=en">English</a></li>
<li><a title="French" href="/fr-fr/[page-slug]" locale="fr">Français</a></li>
</div>
```

This would send the user back to the page they were on, but in the language they need.

I found a solution for this using PHP...

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['target'])) {?><?php echo $_GET['target']; ?><?php } ?>
```

...but the website *has* to be static and can't support the PHP solution.

Is there a similar way to do this with javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve GET parameters from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Comment: That certainly helps to retrieve it, but one big issue I’m running into is getting it to add properly into a href link (since I can’t run script within a href=“”)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Maybe it helps:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  
var params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
var link = params.get("parameter") //add the name of your parameter and it will retrieve the information out of the current URL

var element = document.getElementById('resubscribeLink');
  element.setAttribute("href",link); //puts the parameter value into the href

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code. It may help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
          alert(pageURL);
    });
});
```