# Force html link to open in a new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

There's no easy way to explain this but, I have a website, that links to a online game I've made using asp C#. The website has a link to the game so when the user clicks the link on the site, my game pops up! Simples...

But I want it to pop up in a new Window! but not a browser window... Just... A Window :s

for Example, if you go on www.dofutoshiki.com and click on the "Play Futoshiki in our online player" link, it opens a new window with, just the game. No browser functionality.

I was wondering if anybody out there could shed some light on the subject...

Ive Tried:

```
<a href="blahblah.aspx" target="_blank"> Click me! </a>
```

but it just opens a new tab in the browser!

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/726761/185655

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, you actually want a browser window but without the chrome/UI.

For this, you need to use `window.open()` (javascript) rather than a target attribute.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm will help you.
You have to open the new window by using javascript and disabling the unwanted functionality by passing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need some javascript for this. What you need to look in to is the 
'`window.open(...)`' function.
[Here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) are a few examples.
And [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus) you can play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript Window.open method

```
<a href="javascript:openGame()" target="_blank"> Click me! </a>

 <script>
   function openGame(){
     window.open(blahblah.aspx,'Play Game','width=900,height=790,scrollbars=yes,dependent=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=n           o,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes');
   }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery popup window plugin it is easy to use and more flexible also.

http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html

Answer (score 0):

On site you are referring to, *browser* window is opened. It's configured so that it does not have toolbar, status bar, menu bar, etc.

You can take a look at window opening code in HTML source of the page you are referring to:

```
<a onClick="window.open(this,'playsample','width=900,height=790,scrollbars=yes,dependent=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes');return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is javascript an option?

With javascript it would be something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('blahblah.aspx', 'game','status=0,toolbar=0,width:400,height:300');" > Click here for the game! </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<a href="blahblah.aspx" onclick="window.open(this,'blahblah.aspx', 'width=900,height=790,scrollbars=yes,dependent=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes'); return false">Click me!</a>
```

Or even better, put the onclick code in a function of your own so you can reuse it.