# window.open() not working in firefox to open new popup window using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPopupWindow" runat="server" 
        Text="Popup Window" 
        OnClientClick="PopupWindow();" />
```

JavaScript

```
function PopupWindow() {
    testwindow = window.open("http://google.com", "Google", "menubar=0,addressbar=0, width=500, height=500");
    testwindow.focus();
}
```

Using above code i can open new popup window in IE, but this code is not working in the firefox.
What is the problem with my code?

Comment: How do you call that function?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnPopupWindow" runat="server" Text="Popup Window" OnClientClick="PopupWindow();" />

Comment: could a pop-up blocker be the problem?

Comment: Check firebug, the above code is working fine for me in firefox

Comment: Firefox blocked the popup for me first time but when I disabled the popup blocker it works fine. Seems to be your most likely problem?

Comment: on an unrelated side note your windowFeatures should be `"menubar=yes,location=yes, width=500, height=500"`

Comment: @steven actually firefox is opening new tab for me not popup :(

Comment: And for all browsers to be happy, remove all spaces in the parameters.