# Javascript Popup Browser Tab Will Not Gain Focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using this bit of javascript in a .NET 4.0 web application for IE8:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "popupOpener", "var popup=window.open('Report.aspx');popup.focus();", true);
```

This opens an .aspx page in a new browser tab.

However, it does not give the tab focus, which I would very much like to do. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab ?

Comment: @Moussa: That question appears to deal with whether the new document is opened in a new tab or as a new window. That aside, so long as the JS has a window handler, it should still be able to control focus (among other things).

Comment: A button creates/formats a report document, where it is then stored in a session variable. Then this javascript opens the new aspx window where the report document is loaded into a viewer.

Comment: opening and focusing a new window in a tab will depend on the browser setting and cannot be overridden by javascript. as for firefox, you can set that in its setting.

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support `focus`, and I believe [there are some bugs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1383&can=1&q=window.focus%20type%3aBug&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner) even among those that do.

Try to blur the window before giving it focus. It's bizarre but has worked for folks in the past.

In general:

```
popup_handle.blur();
popup_handle.focus();
```

As applies to your code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "popupOpener", "var popup=window.open('Report.aspx');popup.blur();popup.focus();", true);
```

Comment: Ugh...same behavior. The new tab opens but does not gain focus.

Comment: Is it possible that you don't actually have a window handler. What does console.log say when you log it?