# window.open(url, windowname, opts) opens in new tab instead of new window in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, window

Seems that (try at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kqp5/))

```
window.open('http://www.google.com/', window_name, 'width=400,height=320');
```

completely stops opening new window in Firefox, whatever you put as window_name (_blank, whatever..)! This must have worked recently (year ago), but now it stopped working! It must be some quite new change in Firefox in the past, also [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab) prove this - they worked before but don't work any more!

My suspicion is that it stopped working because the option `"Open new windows in new tab instead"` (Tools / Options / Tabs) is now true by default! It must be a recent change.

My use case really needs to open just a small simple window with legend - opening new tab for this is overkill.

*The problem is that it is a default and normal users are not aware of this setting - they just see that the website behaves strange!*

Is there any way to override Firefox behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: OMG @minitech, have you read my question?? Please read it first to see why it's not a duplicate! I'm even citing it!!

Comment: I have. You know, old questions aren't dead. Try the other solutions, if they don't work, put a bounty or something on the question. This is *the same question*.

Comment: @minitech, if you read the first line of the linked question, it is about `window.open(url)` while my question is about `window.open(url, window, opts)` which is a **big** difference here! This question is about more specific case, which solved the previous question, but now stopped working!!

Comment: Okay. So put a bounty on it saying the current answers are outdated. That's what it's for.

Comment: @minitech, I just tried to explain you that my question is different.

Comment: And I just tried to explain to you that it's actually the same. If you'd like, I can put a bounty on it for you. Yeesh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your fiddle does not contain the code that you posted. This one just works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/HLbLu/

Note that for some reason calling `window.open(...)` is not the same as calling `open(...)`.

Comment: great!!! You made my day, I replaced all my calls to `open` with `window.open` and it works!! It must be some recent change in FF, because until now I only used `open`...

Comment: But now I'm totally confused! How is it possible that `open` and `window.open` aren't the same?? Look at this example: http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/pok_js/window.html

Comment: I posted a [separate question on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966182/what-is-the-difference-between-open-and-window-open)...

Comment: @Pumbaa80 how is open different from window.open?

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin Please see the [follow-up question by Tomas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9970045/27862).

Comment: For what it's worth – taking a hint from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9962027/38108 – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Avoid_resorting_to_window.open() advises "Generally speaking, it is preferable to avoid resorting to window.open() for several reasons: …"

Answer (score 0):

From Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open#section_31

and here:

http://www.gtalbot.org/FirefoxSection/Popup/PopupAndFirefox.html

Comment: I'm not sure that either of these links actually answer the question asked.