# Open link in new window using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i tried below javascript and it does open the url in open window but it clears the url in the current window as well points to the new URL.

window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');

Comment: What browser are you using?  Have you tried it with other browsers?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: I think it's in the rest of your code.  Not this little guy.  :)

Comment: Is window.open() being called from a click event? If so, you'd have to stop the event from bubbling/propagating (which would cause the main browser window to point to the new url as well). Using jquery, event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because the second spot where you have _blank is where the name should be.

I would recommend as the link above that Nathan post suggests doing this. :

```
window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");
```

Then doing some javascript triggering on whatever event is causing the new window to open.

So, lets say it is an image, set the Target="_blank" for the image and then set an OnClick event to call a function with the window.open code in it.

That will do the trick. HTH

Comment: Thank you every one for all the comments and useful information.
1) I added target = _blank attribute via jquery on the ready
2) I added event.PreventDefault() for the OnClick
This two things did the trick.