# ASP.NET VisualBasic2010 web app hyperlink opens new browser tab instead of new browser window

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, browser

When user clicks hyperlink on my ASP.NET page, I want a new browser to open.

I added from toolbox a hyperlink to my target `.html` file,
and added to Sub `Page_Load`

```
<hyperlink ID>.Attributes.Add("target","_blank")
```

But it adds a new tab to browser instead of opening a new browser window.

I tried putting `'_blank'` into `'Target'` attribute of hyperlink property, but still fails.

Weirdly, it works and opens new browser when I run it from VisualStudio, but it only opens new tab if I browse to my web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to control how the new window opens. It could be new window or tab based on user's browsers settings.

[JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)