# How to open the print preview in separate tab

Tags: html, css

I have used the following code for print the page.

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()" style="cursor:default; cursor:hand" target="_blank"><img here>Print</a>
```

If I click the print link the page content will print. I want to display the print preview screen in separate tab. How to fix this?

Comment: It's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab