# Redirect to a new tab using CFLocation - CF9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cflocation

Is there a way to redirect a user to a new window by using CFLocation? As far as I know you cannot use `target=_blank` in CFLocation. Is there another way to do it?

This is my code:

```
    <cfif cgi.PATH_INFO eq "/procedure-page.cfm">
       <cflocation url="http://www.example.com/example/example.cfm?id=XXXXXX&contactid=#returnStruct.contactID#&doctorid=#officeLocation#" addtoken="no" >
    <cfelse>
       <cflocation url="http://www.example.com/example/example.cfm?id=#example#&contactid=#returnStruct.contactID#&doctorid=#officeLocation#" addtoken="no" >
    </cfif>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the cleanest way, but it should work.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfif cgi.PATH_INFO eq "/procedure-page.cfm">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.open("http://www.example.com/example/example.cfm?id=XXXXXX&contactid=#returnStruct.contactID#&doctorid=#officeLocation#", '_blank');
    </script>
<cfelse>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.open("http://www.example.com/example/example.cfm?id=#example#&contactid=#returnStruct.contactID#&doctorid=#officeLocation#", '_blank');
    </script>
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 13):

`<cflocation>` performs a client-side redirect, but it's initiated on the server side (it sends a request with a redirect in the header), so it can't know anything about "tabs" which are a browser thing. CF doesn't know anything about what's going on in the browser.

To do the sort of thing you want to do on the client site, you need to do the browser stuff with Javascript.

Comment: I assume the OP meant open in a new window (not tab).  Browsers can be set to open new windows in tabs. Regardless, I believe you are still correct and this cannot be handled by `CFLocation`.

Comment: Window/tab it makes no difference: ColdFusion doesn't know anything about either of them. ColdFusion never has any interaction with the browser, it only communicates with the web server, which received HTTP requests from the browser, but even the web server doesn't know if the request came from or is intended for a tab / window / frame / whatever. All of that is managed by the browser. So one needs to do it with Javascript. This thread might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab. Either way, it's a JS question not a CF one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Adam is correct in that `CFLocation` cannot ask the browser to open in a new window (or tab).  Something that might interest you however is the `CFWindow` tag.  [See the documentation here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79e6.html)  *Note that `CFWindow` does not open a new browser window either, but creates a `<div>` to simulate a popup window.*  Anyway, it has several options and I thought it might be worth you taking a look at.  Maybe it can handle what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I already saw that but it won't work with what I am attempting to do.

Comment: Fyi, I modified the description to clarify how `cfwindow` actually operates. (Hopefully it is line with your original intent.)

Comment: Thanks @Leigh, your comments/clarifications are always welcome.