# onClick to open window without fixed size

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, size

Essentially - I want the button onClick to open a new window without a fixed size; however, I have no idea how to accomplish this. I've done much research with no success.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
<button class="tealbutton tooltip"
    onClick="window.open('http://google.com','1','width =700,height=500')">         
</button>
```

If I remove the width and height and click on the button - a new tab will open. I want a new window to open instead.

Your help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd paramter to `window.open` also controls the new window's "features". See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.open

Available features:

```
menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes
```

Use `resizable=yes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override whether it opens a new tab or window, it is down to the user's browser preferences. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab).