# submit form to new window without address bar

Tags: html, forms, post, http-post, target

This code will submit a form to a new window

```
<form action="..." method="post" target="_new">
```

But is it possible to make the new window start without the address bar and define its size ?

Comment: I think you need to use javascript. check out the 2nd answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab

Answer (score 9):

Using javascript :

```
<a href="link" onClick="javascript:window.open('http://link','Windows','width=650,height=350,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no');return false")">Link text</a>
```

Comment: i'm not looking for a link.... I already have a form that opens a new window when submitted, but i want that window to come without address bar

Comment: the button of the form is also as a link, we put this link in **action** parameter. you can just include the event OnClick on the button. try it

Answer (score 0):

you can mention header tag on your action page.
is this what you are looking for?

header("location:something.php");