# Querystring truncated with window.open()?

Tags: javascript, query-string, window.open

I want to open a popup window for a printview and I have to pass the object id as get-parameter.

```
var w = window.open('http://example.com/print/?id=42');
```

But JavaScript cuts the querystring at this point and destroys my url.

```
http://example.com/print/
```

Is this a security feature? What can I do to pass the parameter? I cannot use nice urls. :(

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Remove '/' after ~/print. This should work

```
var w = window.open('http://example.com/print?id=42');
```

querystring should be followed by '?'.

Comment: This doesn't matter, I also tried "print.php?id=42". No effect. :( The string is always truncated after "?".

Comment: try like this: window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200"); as mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: This topic is unrelated, because the problem isn't to open that window, the parameters get lost.

Comment: I have the same problem and I didn't include that final `/`. The linked post seems talking about which target window to open , rather than the opener's missing query string.