# How can I open a Popup in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I need to open a Popup window on clicking a button in a xhtml page.
I have written something like that:

```
<p:commandButton type="submit" value="Select User" onclick="showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave()"/>
```

and the java script is like:

```
function showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave()
{
    window.open('./SearchGroupMembersLeaveCalander.xhtml,resizable=no,
    toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,height=450,width=530,top=145,left=235');

    return true;
}
```

But it just opens the page in the current window, no pop up window is opening.Please suggest.

Comment: take a look at these [tutorials](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/10-jquery-popup-window-image-slider-plugins/)

Comment: You should return false to stop `p:commandButton` further processing, also do the change proposed by @Markipe's answer

Comment: Just use `<p:dialog>` instead of all that mess?

Comment: @BalusC I enough googled and everyone provided solution around the <P:dialog>. I am not able to use because of it's library support. I found that dialog attribute is supported by http://primefaces.org/ui library. I think this is primefaces library. Can you please guide me about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one instead

```
function showGrpMemberSearchPageCalenderLeave() { 
     window.open('./SearchGroupMembersLeaveCalander.xhtml','mywindow', 'resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,height=450,width=530,top=145,left=235');
     return true;
 }
```

Syntax

```
window.open(url, windowName, specs);
```

Comment: Hi, @Markipe: It still opens the window in different Tab. No popup opens. :(

Comment: Just try to look at this thread maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: Or if you want use jquery-ui-dialog. "window.open" has a cross-browser issue.

Comment: Hi, This works fine in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox. :(
How can I do it same for FireFox?

Comment: so sad but that's a browser issue you cant do anything about that one. But for less-hassle study about this link http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ for pop-up and http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp for loading page to your pop-up.