# Yii: Open url in new Window, not in new tab

Tags: php, javascript, yii, zii-widgets

Has anyone tryed to set a `CMenu` link to open in a new `window`?

Mine, opens the new window, as blank page and still goes to the requested url

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'items' => array(
        array('label' => Yii::t('admin', 'Live Reports'), 'url' => array('/admin/liveReports/index'), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest, 'active' => ($this->id == 'liveReports'), 'linkOptions' => array('onclick' => 'javascript:window.open("/admin/liveReports/index","x","width=200,height=100")')),
    ),
));
?>
```

Comment: This is not really related to Yii, when tried google had this answer instantly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: @PeterM op has already used the correct code to open in new window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `return false;` from the `onclick` attribute, which is why the current window/tab still navigates to the url:

```
'linkOptions' => array(
    'onclick' => 'javascript:window.open("/admin/liveReports/index","x","width=200,height=100"); return false;'
)
```

Consider using an onclick event handler instead, for good practice, i.e [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Change your **url** property  From

```
   'url' => array('/admin/liveReports/index'),
```

To

```
   'url' => array('#'),
```

Comment: this is not a solution, as this opens a new TAB not a new Window