# Why I can't create new instance of window?

Tags: javascript

Why I can't create a new instance of window.

When I try:

```
var mywin = new window();
```

it throws:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

I guess window is a static object, is there any way of converting static objects to dynamic so that I can do something like this:

```
window.prototype.something = 'value';
```

Could someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just trying to learn how JS works.

Comment: are you after `window.Open()`?? have a look [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: Read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window, I do not think you can have an instance of window without an actual window (page/tab), or iframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window` is a special object representing the global context in Javascript. It is an instance of the `Window` class, but you cannot create instances of that class, as it has some special significance to the interpreter.

(If you just want to create a window, that can be done using the `window.open()` function.)

Answer (score 1):

`window` is not a class, it's a reference to the current `Window` object.

A `Window` object represents a window in the browser, so you can't just create an instance of it. You use the `open` method to open a new window, thereby creating a new `Window` instance:

```
var mywin = window.open('http://www.guffa.com', '_blank');
```

The `_blank` target makes the `open` call actually open a new window, instead of opening a page in the current window.

`Window` is not a class, it's an interface, so it doesn't have a prototype. You can extend the current window with properties, but that will only affect that instance, not all instances:

```
window.something = 'value';
```

Answer (score -2):

The error message is self explanatory! window is not a function, you only use the `new` keyword before a function and then this function is called a constructor function. And what `new` keyword does, is create a new object and set it as the context of the constructor function.