# How can I open a link in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a task to open the link in a new tab.For that I tried the below code

```
window.open($(this).attr("data-MenuLink"), 'target=_new');
```

and also  `window.open($(this).attr("data-MenuLink"), 'target=_blank');`

But the problem is that when I click on the first time, it will load on new tab and work properly. But on second time it will just reload on the previously created tab, rather than new one. I need to open the window in new tab on each click

Comment: What is `this`? in your code?

Comment: try `target=_blank` instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: `target=_blank` is nonsense – `target` is an HTML attribute. The reserved window name for new windows in JavaScript is simply `_blank`.

Comment: @Andy this is the opposite . although i wont argue that this has been answered many times .

Comment: @Andy- I want to open it in a tab,not in new window..

Comment: But the point stands that this is a browser issue.

Comment: <a href="some url" target="_newtab">content of the anchor</a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: @NavajyothCS- I think u diin't got me... right?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('www.yourdomain.com','_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_blank','width=600,height=600')
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 supports "open in new tab", by the property

```
target-new: window | tab | none;
```

See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/)

Otherwise, you can use the browser properties to force windows to open in a new tab.

EDIT: It does not seem to be supported by any browser currently. This seems to work in firefox

```
<a href="some url" target="_newtab">content of the anchor</a>
```

Else, use [this](http://www.paulsilver.co.uk/code/html_working_popup.php) method to resize window immediately, to ensure that popup blockers do not kill your popup

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try This code,

```
 <a href="some url" target="_blank">content of the anchor</a>
```