# window.open() opens window in a new window rather than tabs

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling window.open in javascript on page load

```
window.open(url, "Test Page");
```

It will open a new chrome window and open the page. but when i use same javascript code after page loads. It opens page in new tab.

I need to open the window in new tab rather than new window.
Any one has any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: thanks setec for link

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
window.open(url, "Test Page", '_blank');
```

Comment: I need to open the window in new tab rather than new window.