# OPEN PHP ACTION AFTER CLICKING SUBMIT BUTTON ON A NEW BROWSER/WINDOW

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Good Day, I am trying to make this code run on a new window; Below is my code:

TEST1.PHP

```
<html><head>

<script>
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('1').action = action;
        document.getElementById('1').submit();
    }
</script>

<title>test</title></head><body><form id="1" name="test-1" action="test3.php" method="post">
<input name="fname"><input name="lname"><br>

<input value="Save" name="save" )="" type="submit">
<input value="Nwindow" name="nwindow" onclick="submitForm('test2.php');
window.open='test2.php'" type="submit">
```

TEST2.PHP

```
<html><head>
<form id="2" name="test-2" action="test2.php" method="post">
<title>test</title></head><body>

<input name="fname" value="<?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?>">
<input name="lname" value="<?php echo $_POST['lname']; ?>">
<br>
</form>
</body></html>
```

They both work correctly but what i wanted for nwindow button to perform TEST2.PHP on another window/browser; I tried window open but it is not working.

I am new with javascript so i am not sure it this can be done.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This answer might help you out :)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/726803/3415760

Comment: You should not use numbers as IDs for Javascript. You should change your form id to something else

Comment: thanks for that reminder cronoklee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `target="_blank"` on your first form.

Read the manual for more info on forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

**EDIT:** If you want to only load the new tab for *one* of the submit buttons, do this:

```
<form id="myForm" name="test-1" action="test3.php" method="post">
<input name="fname"><input name="lname"><br>

<input value="Save" name="save" type="button" onclick="submitForm('test3.php','_self');">
<input value="Nwindow" name="nwindow" type="button" onclick="submitForm('test2.php','_blank');">
```

Then in your JS:

```
function submitForm(action,target)
{
  document.getElementById('myForm').target = target
  document.getElementById('myForm').action = action;
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: target="_blank" just opens a new tab but he wants a new window.

Comment: you mean on TEST1.PHP? If i do that then both buttons will open a new window once they have been executed; Is it possible for only NWINDOW button to perform the new window?

Comment: Sure - I've updated my answer to show you how to do this

Comment: Thanks cronoklee i finally got the output i wanted :)