# How to open new two tabs in PHP using header

Tags: javascript, php, header

I'm trying to open a new tab with Php,

```
header("location:print_register.php?recpt_no=".$recpt_no);
```

like this i need to open new two tab like this

```
header("location:print_register.php?recpt_no=".$recpt_no);

header("location:print_generate.php?recpt_no=".$recpt_no);
```

it need to open new two tab with passing values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to specify a window to open as a tab. Whether it opens as a new tab or a new window is entirely dependent upon the browser and its configuration. The best way to look at these situation is to not distinguish a tab from a window and move on from there.

Having said that, as others have already mentioned, it is impossible to open a new window via PHP. The `header()` function will do nothing more than a redirect of the current window. You need to have this occur via a standard link

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_new" />
```

or JavaScript

```
window.open('http://www.google.com/');
```

In your particular case, you want to launch two, so you can do this (assuming you can use a link) by combining the two

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_new" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com/')" />
```

or launching both via JavaScript. Here's an example that will allow you to store target addresses in an array and launch them all:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = new Array('http://www.google.com/', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        window.open(links[i]);
    }
}
```

The links do not need to be absolute, so you can use relative paths such as `./print_register.php?recpt_no=`.

Now, since you're pulling part of the address from the PHP, things get a little more complicated, but not by much.  You, basically, just need to use the PHP to complete the rendered JavaScript:

```
<?php
    $recpt_no = 'RN426762';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var links = new Array('./print_register.php?recpt_no=<?php echo $recpt_no; ?>', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
                for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                    window.open(links[i]);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

You don't need to put the entire script into a PHP `echo`. Instead, write the code normal and `echo` the PHP variables where you need it. It'll keep the PHP-side of the code cleaner, and help a little with the performance, but probably not noticeable.

I hope this helps. ^^

**JSFiddles**

- Link: http://jsfiddle.net/zLh3dusx/
- JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/89boc383/
- Combined: http://jsfiddle.net/b9zne07r/
- JavaScript Array: http://jsfiddle.net/9ohLxxLo/

Comment: I added PHP integration, since I overlooked that part of the link is coming from the PHP. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

With header it's just not possible. Header will redirect you to a page.

Something like this would work:

```
<a href='xy.php' target='_blank'>text</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab?rq=1 - open new tab / window using javascript. +1 from me, as with php it is of course impossible.

Comment: in forms action it will open two windows it is possible

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot do this, but you can do something very similar with JavaScript.

I have accomplished this before using jQuery, with a link and a simple 100ms timeout.

```
Checkout.
http://jsfiddle.net/hw3t1syz/
```

Answer (score 0):

finally me itself got anwser

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>   
window.open( '/print_register.php?recpt_no=$recpt_no' )
</script>";
```

use it it will open new tab