# Open a link in new tab with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

I want to open a link in a new tab.
To do this I am writing a code like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('ul.sf-menu.sf-navbar li li a:contains("/events/aqr-investment-symposium-for-merrill-lynch/custom-20-a60da1b5daf74421bb19860b0769e3ba.aspx")').attr("target","_blank");
});
```

It's not working for me.

I cannot touch the HTML code.
I can just make it done with jquery or javaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the href of anchor element for opening in new window:

```
window.open($('ul.sf-menu.sf-navbar li li a:contains("/events/aqr-investment-symposium-for-merrill-lynch/custom-20-a60da1b5daf74421bb19860b0769e3ba.aspx")').attr('href'));
```