# open actionlink in new window instead of new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried almost all the links and solution on google first page . but all the answers led to me in new tab instead of new window. While i want to open ActionLink in new window . Please provide something other than `target = "_blank"`

Comment: Show the code from which you want to open the window

Comment: whats wrong with target = "_blank" if it produces the intended effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: This behavior depends on Browser preferences of user. You cannot control it from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
<a href="#" onclick="openNewWindow();">open</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openNewWindow() {
        window.open("/values/index", "New Window", "height=500,width=500");
    }
</script>
```

In the url assume **Values** is your controller and **Index** as your action

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

to be sure to open a new window without `target=_blan`k (which will open a new tab), you might have to use some js. It will be difficult to achieve it only with HTML as all browser uses tabs nowadays. 
try: `window.open("http://mynewwindowurl")`

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open in a new window</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://mynewwindowurl.com");
}
</script>
```

details: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

hope it helps

also check this link for js window open with specs: [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)