# HTML How to open this URL in new window?

Tags: html, href

This is the code:

```
<a href="FAKE_URL" onclick="document.location.href = 'REAL_URL'; return false;">
<img src="IMAGE"></a>
```

I have already tried:

```
<a href="FAKE_URL" onclick="document.location.href = 'REAL_URL'; return false;" target="_blank">
<img src="IMAGE"></a>
```

but not working

Comment: Why you want the onclick event there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: `<input type="button" name="XX" onclick="window.open('yourfile.html','','width=750px,height=1000px,left=150,top=0,toolbar=no,status=no,resizable=no,titlebar=no').focus();">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="../html-link.html" target="popup" onclick="window.open('../html-link.html','name','width=600,height=400')">Open page in new window</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **`window.open('url','_blank')`** to open after the onclickevent a new tab:

```
<a href="https://google.com" onclick="window.open('https://youtube.com','_blank'); return false;">click here for a new tab</a>
```

or you can use **`window.open('url','','width=,height=')`** to open a new window:

```
<a href="https://google.com" onclick="window.open('https://youtube.com','','width=800,height=700'); return false;">click here for a new window...</a>
```

In this example it will open **youtube** (`REAL_URL`) instead of **google** (`FAKE_URL`)

**[> JSFiddle - Example](https://jsfiddle.net/e08w94mn/)**

---

**Explanation:**

Your mistake was that the add of **`target="_blank"`** changes the behaviour of your `<a href="..."></a>`, but not your `document.location.href='...'`. So without the `document.location.href='...'` it would open the **`FAKE_URL`** in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

To open file in a new window, use

```
onclick="window.open('yourfile.html','','width=750px,height=1000px,left=150,top=‌​0,toolbar=no,status=no,resizable=no,titlebar=no').focus();"
```