# How to open a browser window without any bars like address bars, bookmarks bars etc in javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, dojo

I am looking to open a url (html file) without any kind of address bars, bookmarks bar so that the user just sees the application window. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: You can do it on mac from the terminal for Chrome by setting up an alias `alias chrome='/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome'` and then running `chrome --app https://smile.amazon.com`

Comment: @nroose you need an `=` between `--app` and the URL, e.g., `chrome --app=https://google.com` (but, alas, that's not what the OP asked anyway...)

Comment: @raner Thanks you!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
window.open(url,'window','toolbar=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes');
```

You can read about these and more of the options [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: how compatible is this with different browsers?

Comment: @Dheeraj the linked page in the answer says it’s compatible with all of the major browsers

Comment: This has the address bar. (except Opera)