# JS opened window has no bookmarks bar (chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window

The following JS code will open a new window WITHOUT bookmarks bar in chrome.

```
javascript:(function() {
window.open('https://example.com', '', 'menubar=yes,location=yes,status=yes,channelmode=yes,toolbar=yes,resizable=yes');

})();
```

So.. how do I open a NORMAL browser window, like that one we get by CTRL+N?
I've read this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp but there is nothing about it.

Also, I've seen some questions that are opposite to mine : [How to open a browser window without any bars like address bars, bookmarks bars etc in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710446/how-to-open-a-browser-window-without-any-bars-like-address-bars-bookmarks-bars)

So I guess its possible to show them. Thanks..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features

Comment: @Jonasw it I still don't get it, there is only article about personalbar but that's not for Chrome

Comment: well then its not possible

Comment: =( this is sad.. I won't close this question maybe someone knows a workaround