# How to launch a window in a whole new broswer?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

With `:target => '_blank'` in Rails view, a new browser `tab` within the same browser could be launched as below.

```
<%= link_to 'Dataset', @dataset_url, target: '_blank' %>
```

However if we want to open a window in a whole new browser, how do we accomplish that?

Comment: Short answer you can't, you can open a new window of the current browser with `window.open(url);` in js

Comment: You go into your browser options and unselect "open new windows in a new tab instead" (FireFox). It's not the webserver's choice to make. I wouldn't be surprised if there is a way to do it, but ... you shouldn't want to do it. Don't override user choices, it just makes people (me) angry when using sites like that.

Comment: `TessellatingHeckler`, angry with a new window? I want to present information in a whole new browser and this is my question about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes absolutely possible with javascript pls this link http://progblog10.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/rails-opening-new-browser-tab-or-window.html

Comment: Tried the `onclick:` and it opened a new tab but not a whole new browser. It behaves the same as `target: '_blank'`

Comment: You should add some additional parameters as well, window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200") check this same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: This one works: `<%= link_to 'Dataset', @dataset_url, onclick: "var w = window.open(this.href, height=200,width=200); w.focus(); return false;" %>`