# How to use new window instead of new tab display gridview data on click event in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my code:

```
Response.Write("window.open('loginfo.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument 
"','height=200,width=200,alwaysRaised=yes')");
```

But still it didn't work as new window instead of new tab.

Now I got like shows data in gridview in new tab, but I need to show like new window.

For that what should I do?

update:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log Info">
      <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnloginfo" Text="Log-Info" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Book_id") %>' Onclick="loginfo_click"/>
           </ItemTemplate>
          <ControlStyle BackColor="#FF0066" ForeColor="White" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

cs:

```
  protected void loginfo_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)(sender);           
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                 this,
                 GetType(),
                 "OPEN_WINDOW",
                 "window.open('loginfo.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument + "','height=200,width=200,alwaysRaised=yes')",true);           
        }
```

Comment: You can use `Thickbox.js` for this purpose.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: can you show sample code?..

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough time to create a sample for you. You can search for live demo in google. Here's one [Thickbox](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/)

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: can you please see my updated post?

Comment: `window.open` creates a new window. You need a `Modal` to show data, there is no built in method in javascript to do that. You'll have to use a library which does it for you. 2 users have suggested you 2 different and very nice libraries. Go to the documentation, read it and use it. Don't ask for ready to use copy and paste code try to do it yourself.

Comment: @Shaharyar: I removed modal.. but event it didn't work as per width and height.

Comment: Which modal you used? Show the code where you used modal and it didn't work.

Comment: I didn't use modal.. but if i use particular width and height...

Comment: I referred this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `script>` tags and `_blank` to open it in new window:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('WebForm2.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument + "','_blank', 'height=200,width=200,alwaysRaised=yes')</script>");
```

Comment: it shows error scriptmanager doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Add script manager to your page. In aspx code, just drag and drop from toolbox

Comment: I edited my by follow your answer, It shows error, can you please updated post?

Comment: You don't need to use `Response.Write("<script>");`, `ScriptManager` will handle it.

Comment: I replaced second parameter with `GetType()`, check again.

Comment: Just remove the `ID` from script tag in asp code. I mistakenly put it there.

Comment: please see my updated post, i showed aspx and cs code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99911/discussion-between-shaharyar-and-rani).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use FancyBox : [GitHub](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox)

this is example result on my project...

[image]

[image]

I need to help you but i not have mor time , sorry !