# Open the URL in New Window in html and Javascript

Tags: html

I'm trying to Open the given URL in New window, not in new TAB.

people are suggesting to use window open

`function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
}`

but it's opening the url in same browser in new Tab. but i need to open it in same browser and new window

like below image

[image]

Can Any one help me,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','newwin', 'width=' + window.screen.availWidth + ',height=' + window.screen.availHeight + ',screenX=0,screenY=0,top=0,left=0left=0,top=0,scrollbars,resizable,replace=true');
```

The above code will get the screen height and width according to the screen resolution

Answer (score 2):

You can use this coding to open the url in new browser window.Working perfectly:

```
<script>
function pop_up(url){
window.open(url,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=1076,height=768,directories=no,location=no') 
}
</script>

 <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="pop_up(this);">OPEN</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it with a specific height and width.

```
window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");
```