# How to control the minimize using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wantt to complete my project but there was a problem in minimizing and want to control the minimize

Comment: i just want to disable the minimize in browser so my application will not broken .

Comment: Oh i understood now...

Comment: help me please so I can pass my subject

Comment: I'm not sure about these _features_... anyways, give a look in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2315916/6188402).

Comment: thank you very much . it was the correct code for my project

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :)