# window.open without onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

i create ajax call to get data. and in success function i add window.open(), without onclick event the result of window open is incorrect. the result is window open as tab not new window. i have add name in window.open(). and the url is incorrect.

```
$.ajax({
data: "ticket="+invoice,
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url('controller');?>",
cache: false,
dataType:"json",
success: function(response) {
    window.open(url,windowName);
} });
```

url in address bar of tab is `controller_url "url,windowName"`
[image]

in my case, correct url in address bar is `http://localhost/cinema/adm/cahier/ticket/kode_ticket`
it normal if i call window.open() in onclick event. what i want is open new window popup automatically after ajax success

Comment: Have you tried it with the relative url, as url = "/ticket/160324201"

Comment: try if this works window.open(url,  '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');

Comment: First of all you can not open new window on a browser without any user activity. Browsers prohibit such attempts made by web sites to secure user's experience.

Comment: window.open(url,'_blank','location=yes,height=0,width=0,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/726803/3635079

Comment: Pop Up Blocker. No User Action = blocked. Why do you need an Ajax call anyway. Just post a form to a new window.

Comment: Browser might block `window.open()` request due to popup blocking mechanism. Browsers will often block `window.open` unless they're called in direct response to a user action. That's why your click handler works (a click is a user action) but your AJAX handler success doesn't.

Comment: i think it work if there is any user activity as trigger. like @mertyildiran says

Comment: @Shubhranshu it work, thanks

Comment: @Dedi, Have Good Coding Time !!!

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the window.open method you may specify the window width and height, or other parameters and it shall open a new window, which you would specify more than likely the current window size, or something that works for you.

Like so;

```
window.open(url, windowName, "height:500,width:300")
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: i was doing that, but it can only work on onclick event