# Open random image in new window

Tags: javascript, html

I can't make this open the image in a new window (not tab).

This script is placed in `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function randomImg1() {
    var myImage1 = new Array();
    myImage1[0] = "1.jpg";
    myImage1[1] = "2.jpg";
    myImage1[2] = "3.jpg";
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImage1.length);
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" 
      + myImage1[random] + "' alt='image'></img>";

  }

</script>
```

My button is placed in `<body>`:

```
<button onclick="randomImg1();OpenInNewTab();">click</button>    
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: you are writing an image tag in a DOM element with the ID "image". Try `window.open(myImage1[random])` instead. Though you might run into problems with popup blockers.

Comment: wher in the code should i add window.open(myImage1[random])

Comment: replace `document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" 
      + myImage1[random] + "' alt='image'></img>";` with `window.open(myImage1[random]);`

Comment: PS: most browsers will open a new tab (not a window). To open a new window, you need to add the specs parameter. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/726803/7933618 and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: oh, and you probably need to specify the whole path to the image. Either hardcode it or if it's relative to the current location, you can use the current path with either `window.location.href` if you are on a "folder" level, or if your current URL contains a filename (like index.html), you can build the path like `window.open(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + myImage1[random]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp to open a new window. Add the `spec` parameter to make it open as a new window instead of a tab. And make sure to pass the full path of the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function randomImg1() {
    var myImage1 = new Array();
    myImage1[0] = "1.jpg";
    myImage1[1] = "2.jpg";
    myImage1[2] = "3.jpg";
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImage1.length);
    // create the full image URL
    var imageUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + myImage1[random];
    // open in a new window. ideally use the image's size for w and h
    window.open(imageUrl, '_blank', 'height=300,width=300');
  }
</script>
```