# Open window.location.href location in a new window

Tags: javascript

How can I open a URL specified in `window.location.href` in new window?

```
function callThisFunction1() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("lookup1");
    var unit = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    if (unit == "M") {
        window.location.href='site.com'+document.getElementById("Var").value;
    }
    else if (unit == "S") {
        window.location.href='site.com'+document.getElementById("Var1").value;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: I think you'll need to use the window.open() function instead of `window.location.href=`  There's some details about that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: To add: `window.open()` behaves differently with absolute and relative URLs. If you want to go to a different site all together make sure to add `http://` or `https://`. Example:  `window.open("https://www.youtube.com", "_blank")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function onDropownChange(e){

  var value = document.getElementById('dropDown').value;
  switch(value){
    case 'A':
      window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');
    case 'B':
      window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/','_blank');
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<select name="example" id="dropDown" onchange="onDropownChange()">
 <option value="A">Option A</option>
 <option value="B">Option B</option>
</select>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please replace this `window.location.href='site.com'+document.getElementById("Var1").value;` and this `window.location.href='site.com'+document.getElementById("Var").value;` line as followos

```js
window.open('site.com'+document.getElementById("Var1").value,'_blank');
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.open(url)` instead of `location.href`

`window.open()` is a method that you can pass a URL to that you want to open in a new window while `window.href` is not a method, it's a property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser. Changing the value of the property will redirect the page.

Example:

`window.location.href = url; //Will take you to URL.`

`window.open(url); //This will open url in a new window.`

`window.open()` can be used with parameters

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. Here i am assuming that you want to current location.href in new tab. If you want some other url, you can open that as well. Just pass the value in window.open.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Should open href in new window</p>

<button onclick="openTab()">Click here</button>

<script>
function openTab() {
  window.open(window.location.href);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are telling window to change *the current frame* location by calling:

`window.location.href = 'mysite.com';`.

What you want to do is to issue a new frame, you'll have to use `window.open()` method instead:

`var newWindow = window.open([url],[newWindowName],[config]);`

full reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open