# angular should open the link in new window

Tags: angular

how to open below route  in new window. I want this route which is for `recorder` component to open in new window

```
  closeDialog(requestType) {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.router.navigate(["recorder"], { state: { example: requestType } });
  }
```

Comment: `{ example: requestType }` - is this query param?

Comment: @topmoon yes it is query param

Comment: You can use the javascript method `window.open( "recorder" )` for a new window. I don't think you can pass a state like this though. Maybe consider routing like this using routing parameters instead of state

Answer (score 0):

router.navigate is to navigate in the same window. You need to use `window.open` to open a new tab:

```js
closeDialog(requestType) {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    window.open(`${window.origin}/recorder?exampe=${requestType}`, '_blank');
}
```

**Update**

You need to specify the third parameter in the window.open method to open a completely new window:

```js
closeDialog(requestType) {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    window.open(`${window.origin}/recorder?exampe=${requestType}`, '_blank', 'width=1024,height=768');
}
```

Similar answer here:

[JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: i want to open in new window not in new tab and it is opening home page in new tab

Comment: it is opening homepage in new window

Comment: please give me the absolute path to the `recorder` page

Comment: i have figured out to open recorder on new window but i am unable to pass state

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the **Angular Router** and use **.then**

```
    closeDialog(requestType: any) {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    const link = `${window.origin}/recorder?exampe=${requestType}`;
    this.router.navigate(["recorder"], { state: { example: requestType } }).then((result: any) => {  window.open(link, '_blank'); });
  }
```

I added the Angular Router link below fit you'd like to see what other cool stuff it can do.

In keeping with the other answers the link should be whatever you declared - so in the example your link was what I placed, I just type checked it in vs code so I believe this should work.
https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: what does `link` refer to in `{  window.open(link, '_blank'); }`

Comment: I updated my answer sorry - link is your link I updated the answer to show you how to do that properly via a const or let, I used const but it doesn't really matter.  Good luck 

Comment: what above code is doing that it is navigating my current window to component `recorder` component and opening new tab with my home page