# Running JS file in Python

Tags: javascript, python

I am a Python user, but I have never worked with JavaScript. I am trying to run a JS file in my Python Flask Project, but I do not know how to make it work.
I am using the Naked library in my python code to call the JS file like this:

```
responseJS = muterun_js('sign.js', parameters)
signatureData = responseJS.stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

This is supposed to work, but I do not know how to create the sign.js file. I have to import one package to make it work, and then run some JS code which is not important for the purpose of this question.
So, the question is, how do I import a library in my JS file, so once I call it from my python works? The package is: require("@sorare/crypto")

Thank you for your help

Comment: see if changing to `, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0'` in `window.open` works, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315916/12652373)

Comment: Also worth nothing that browser preferences can supersede your code. I don't know the full rules for each browser but it may be a useful direction to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it did not work