# Is there any way to open the react app only in a new window(Not a new tab)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I'm currently developing a banking app using react.js so I need to secure my app form client side.
is there any way to open the app only in new window(Not a new tab)?

I need
When a user type the url in browser the app should open automatically in a new widow.

like this window
[image]

And if you know any other security features or other solutions please let me know.
thanks

Comment: Render full react app in  a new window

Comment: No. Whether a new "window" is a tab or a desktop window (or something else) is under the control of the person using the browser, not you.

Comment: I'm curious to know how opening it in a new window as opposed to a new tab will make it more secure

Comment: @Spikatrix you can see the sample image the address bar is disabled and there is no extensions there.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this answer? This may resolve your problem.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/726803/21499903)

TL;DR:

They use

```
window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. But how to open full app in new window in reactjs

Comment: Please add some more details to your answer other than the referenced link only.